# Is there a way to track\fix the `libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw` exception

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, objective-c++, libc++

As the title stands, is there a proper way of tracking down the `libc++abi.dylib__cxa_throw:` and fixing it. See the image below with the only info I have:

[image]

Also, here is the stack trace, not much going on there:
[image]

Most of what I found is the suggestions to catch Objective-C breakpoints only like so:

[image: Objective-C exceptions only]

But I'm looking for explanation why it happens, and want to fix it properly, at least understand why it occurs. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!